# Comparar duas Lista

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma lista

```
List<Comentarios> comentarios
List<Comentarios> comentariosSP
```

A primeira lista eu recebo os dados de um webserver, a segunda de um SharedPreferences.

Eu tentei compara-las

```
comentarios.equals(comentariosSP)
```

mas ele sempre retorna false, mesmo eu sabendo que as listas são idênticas.

lembrando que eu preciso verificar se os dados dos atributos são os mesmos. EX:

```
comentarios.get(0).getComentario().equals(comentariosSP.get(0).getComentario())
```

Tem como fazer isso sem percorrer toda a lista?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `equals()` da List se sobre-escrever o método `equals()` da classe *Comentarios* de forma a indicar quando dois objectos *Cometarios* são iguais:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // verifica se é o mesmo objecto
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    // verifica se é null
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    // verifica tipo e cast
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    Comentarios comentarios = (Comentarios) o;
    // Comparação atributo a atributo
    // Note que cada um dos atributos têm também de implementar correctamente o método equals()
    return Objects.equals(atributo1, comentarios.atributo1)
            && Objects.equals(atributo2, comentarios.atributo2) && .....;
}
```

Nota: Duas listas são iguais se tiverem o mesmo número de itens, iguais e  pela mesma ordem.

Comment: Muito obrigado! serviu como uma luva para mim!

Answer (score 0):

Quando você compara com o método comentarios.equals(comentariosSP), você está comparando o endereço de memória em que a lista está alocada.

utilizando o equals() da List você compara os valores em sí.